# Remove routing-container of leaflet-routing

Tags: leaflet, routing

How to remove the whole container (see picture below) of leaflet-routing that includes distance and travel time via a button in my index.html?

[image: unwanted container]

If i remove *line 3508* of leaflet-routing-machine.js: `return this._container;` the container is not visible. But this way is not an option.

Comment: That doesn't look like it's shown by default with `leaflet-routing-machine` (at least I've never seen it when I used the library). Are there any other Leaflet or routing-machine widgets in your map code, if so, can you show your map code?

Comment: @chrki Its the via CSS modified _leaflet-routing-container_ that normaly contains additional informations about your route. See here: http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `show: false` and `collapsible: false` to the control didn't seem to do the trick. But you can manipulate the container's CSS with Javascript this way:

```
control._container.style.display = "None";
```

To show it again later you can reverse this by doing:

```
control._container.style.display = "Block";
```

Comment: Thats not what iam looking for. Im looking for a way to remove this via a command in JS

Comment: @howard.D I edited my answer

Comment: this actually did the trick. But im still struggling: i wanted to remove the container to change the ordner of my controls. A Button should be on top of topright ordner. Without removing the the rounting_container it overlays an input field. By using control._container.style.display = "None"; and control._container.style.display = "Block"; The container hides and then appears in the same position again and still hides my control.

Comment: solved: just used the CSS hacks for my button instead of for the routing container